# SQL Server CLR Function Set timeout

Tags: sql-server, clr, sqlclr

I have a SQL Server CLR function that is doing quite a bulky task.

I am calling it from another SPROC and I want the SPROC to give the CLR function 10 seconds to return results. If the CLR function hasn't returned in this time thenI want the calling SPROC to go and do alternative processing.

So is setting a timeout on a CLR call possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Service Broker to call the CLR proc and then include the standard WAITFOR...TIMEOUT I would think.